Non-trivial "energy coverings" of reciprocal space
My question is about sheets of the Fermi surface and their mathematical properties.
As far as I understand, in the one-electron approximation with a weak periodic potential (Bloch approximation) you obtain a decomposition of the one-electron Hilbert $\mathcal{H}$ space into a direct integral
$$\mathcal{H} = \int_{\widehat{G}} \mathcal{H}_{[k]} d[k],$$
where $\widehat{G} \simeq \mathbf{R}^3/G$ is the quotient of $k$-space by the dual lattice $G$, and for a $G$-orbit $[k] = k+G$ the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{[k]} \simeq l^2([k]) \approx l^2(G)$ describes solutions whose Fourier transform is supported only on $[k]$. The spectrum of each $\mathcal{H}_{[k]}$ is a discrete set, which you can write as a union
$$\mathcal{S}(k) \equiv \{ E_n(k) : n \in \mathbf{N} \},$$
where $n \in \mathbf{N}$ is the band number and $k \mapsto E_n(k)$ is a continuous function, at least in the interior of the first brillouin zone.
My question now is this: Is is true that the $E_n$ are $G$-periodic, i.e.
$$E_n(k+g) = E_n(k) \quad \forall g \in G?$$
Or asked differently, are there examples where
$$E_n(k+g) = E_m(k)$$
for a $m \neq n$? Or in other words, is $k \mapsto \mathcal{S}(k)$ a non-trivial covering of reciprocal space?
Partial answer: It seems that the answer is no in general, since for the free case ($V=0$) you basically have energy bands $E_g(k) = E(k+g)$ parametrized by $g \in G$, where $E(k) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}k^2$ is the free energy, because in that case
$$E_g(k+g') = E_{g+g'}(k),$$
so the covering would be the universal covering $\mathbf{R}^3 \twoheadrightarrow \mathbf{R}^3/G$.
However, what I'd be really interested in is how it looks in non-trivial examples.

Related

Note that your consideration of the free case is actually able to tell you more than you think. In the easiest view, you have a restriction of the $k$ to just the 1BZ and no more, in which case you have no double-counting, and everything is nice. The view you considered is the case where you have periodic extension to the rest of the BZ. That is particularly fine if you have a periodic system. However, if you have just one atom, then you should use the extended zone scheme, in which case going out of the 1BZ implies going up the $n$ counting. Ashcroft & Mermin covers this nicely.
